# Htaccess remove query string from 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, magento

**I write 301 redirect as below**

```
Redirect 301 /catalogue/novelty_linen_q_t/spongebob_squarepants/spongebob_squarepants_quilt_cover_wonderland/image/?size=275x275&helper=1281395930.79 http://www.thebedroom.com.au/manchester/character-bedding.html?size=275x275&helper=1281395930.79
```

**but when I goes to**
http://www.thebedroom.com.au/catalogue/novelty_linen_q_t/spongebob_squarepants/spongebob_squarepants_quilt_cover_wonderland/image/?size=275x275&helper=1281395930.79

**it redirect**
http://www.thebedroom.com.au/manchester/character-bedding.html?size=275x275&helper=1281395930.79

........
I need redirect
http://www.thebedroom.com.au/manchester/character-bedding.html

Comment: remove the query string from the redirect?

Comment: yes i redirect using 301 to new url, but it redirects with the query string so i need to remove that query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the query string from your Redirect directive, this is what you have: (make sure to scroll all the way to the right to see the comments)

```
#                                                                                                                           This question mark right here is why you have a query string in your redirect ---------v
Redirect 301 /catalogue/novelty_linen_q_t/spongebob_squarepants/spongebob_squarepants_quilt_cover_wonderland/image/?size=275x275&helper=1281395930.79 http://www.thebedroom.com.au/manchester/character-bedding.html?size=275x275&helper=1281395930.79
```

Not really sure why it's working at all, but you need to remove everything **AFTER** the `?`, leaving the `?` there. That does have the unsightly side-effect of a stray question mark, but you can get rid of that using mod_rewrite, replacing the `Redirect` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalogue/novelty_linen_q_t/spongebob_squarepants/spongebob_squarepants_quilt_cover_wonderland/image/?$ /manchester/character-bedding.html? [L,R=301]
```